# c# WCF getting list of elements values

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a piece of XML example below

```
<job>
   <refno>XXX</refno>
   <specialisms>
       <specialism>1</specialism>
       <specialism>2</specialism>
   </specialisms>
</job>
```

How using WCF c# do I serialise these values into a list?

I currently have...

```
[DataMember]
public SpecialismList specialisms { get; set; }

[CollectionDataContract(Name = "specialisms", ItemName = "specialism")]
public class SpecialismList : List<int> { }
```

But it isn't currently working... any tips?

Comment: hi, WCF is for communication - while it can use SOAP to serialize it's data it is not the right tool to read a XML-file into a object. You can use VS directly to get models to some xml-schema - just google for it

Comment: Carsten, the XML will be posted to a wcf webservice, of which I will then serialize that to an object using the datacontracts etc.

Comment: You will almost certainly need to use XMLSerializer (not DataContractSerializer) in order to get fine level control over how your Serialized Entities 'look' when in XML format.

Answer (score 0):

This data contract should work out just fine to serialize to the XML you posted (see code below). What is the problem you're having?

```
public class StackOverflow_7386673
{
    [DataContract(Name = "job", Namespace = "")]
    public class Job
    {
        [DataMember(Order = 0)]
        public string refno { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Order = 1)]
        public SpecialismList specialisms { get; set; }
    }

    [CollectionDataContract(Name = "specialisms", ItemName = "specialism", Namespace = "")]
    public class SpecialismList : List<int> { }

    public static void Test()
    {
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        DataContractSerializer dcs = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(Job));
        Job job = new Job
        {
            refno = "XXX",
            specialisms = new SpecialismList { 1, 2 }
        };
        XmlWriterSettings ws = new XmlWriterSettings
        {
            OmitXmlDeclaration = true,
            Indent = true,
            IndentChars = "  ",
            Encoding = new UTF8Encoding(false),
        };
        XmlWriter w = XmlWriter.Create(ms, ws);
        dcs.WriteObject(w, job);
        w.Flush();
        Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray()));
    }
}
```